# If I use a static method to create an object and add it to a disposable instance of another object, is the object created in the static method static?

Tags: c#, .net, static

I am seeing some strange, buggy behavior in some .NET code, and I'm wondering if it has to  do with how I've set things up.

I have a non-static class with a method. In this method, I create a new instance of a disposable class. I then use a static helper method to add something to that disposable instance.

Sometimes the code throws an exception at a certain point (by timing out). I don't know why, and this question isn't about why that happens. But what happens next is that *if* an exception was thrown, the next time the code runs, which supposedly would create a new instance of my main class, and a new instance of the disposable object within that new instance, then a *different* bit of code involving the disposable object also causes a timeout exception, much earlier in the process.

Here is a simplified example of what's happening:

```
public sealed class MyClass : OtherClass
{
    protected override void MyMethod(ContextInfo context)
    {
        using (DisposableClass disposableInstance = new DisposableClass(context.URL))
        {
            Helper.ConditionallyAddThingy(disposableInstance, context.thingInfo, context.URL);

            foreach(var foo in fooCollection)
            {
                // 1. initially I can make as many of these calls as I want,
                //    and they all finish successfully. if there were no
                //    timeout issues in section 2 below, the next time this
                //    runs, supposedly in a new instance of MyClass, and with
                //    a new instance of "disposableInstance", it again runs perfectly fine,
                //    no matter how many "foo"s there are.
                
                // 2. see below

                // 3. _if_ I had a timeout exception previously in section 2 below,
                //    the next time this runs, supposedly in a _new_ instance of MyClass,
                //    and with a _new_ instance of "disposableInstance",
                //    I get a timeout exception _here_  on the first "foo", and don't even get to section 2.

                // make a call that does _not_ have to do with file streams
                SomeResponse response = disposableInstance.AskForSomething(foo);
                disposableInstance.ExecuteQuery();
            }

            foreach(var fileInfo in fileInfoCollection)
            {
                // 2. if there is only one file, the call succeeds, however
                //    if there is more than one file, the request for the
                //    second file casuses a System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out

                var fileUrl = fileInfo["URL"];
                FileIshThing fileIsh = File.OpenBinaryDirect(disposableInstance, fileUrl);
                disposableInstance.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}

internal static class Helper
{
    internal static void ConditionallyAddThingy(DisposableClass disposableInst, string thingInfo string contextUrl)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thingInfo))
        {
            Thing thing = new Thing(thingInfo);
            Uri uri = new Uri(contextUrl);
            thing.Uri = uri;

            ThingCollection collection = new ThingCollection();
            collection.Add(thing);

            disposabeInst.ExecuteWebRequestEventHandler += delegate (object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                eventArgs.ThingCollection = collection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something about creating the `Thing` or `ThingCollection`, or adding the event receiver in the static method that makes those things static themselves, so that the next time through, I'm not really creating new ones but reusing the ones from the last time the method executed?

I don't understand how an error condition in a previous (and disposed of) instance of an object can affect a new instance of the object that may not necessarily meet the conditions for causing the error.

Comment: It doesn't look like `ConditionallyAddThingy` is doing anything that would cause `Helper` to keep the instance of `DisposableClass` you pass it, or any of the objects it creates (`Thing`, `ThingCollection`) to be rooted to the `Helper` static class, assuming that is what you meant by "makes those things static themselves". If they were being rooted by `Helper`, you're creating new instances in `ConditionallyAddThingy` so you wouldn't be reusing the previous ones. You'd just be leaking memory because those instances couldn't be collected.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I _thought_ should be happening, thanks for confirming.  Thought I might be losing it there for a minute. :) So... next question is - what's clogging up my subsequent instances of `MyClass` and `DisposableClass`?

Comment: To answer the question asked in the title, think about the very common `Parse` and `TryParse` factory pattern, which is (one or both) static method used to create instances (probably using a private constructor) and from the perspective of the consuming code is an alternative to the constructor just with a different error strategy.  So the lifetime of the created objects are exactly the same as if they were constructed.

Comment: For an example of that pattern see `Guid.Parse`.  There's nothing "static" about the returned `Guid` object.